# amazon ecs freeing space on docker storage

Tags: docker, amazon-ebs, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to cleanup space on docker EBS for Amazon ECS instance. On ECS docker is using separate partition to store all his FS layers:

```
[ec2-user@]$ sudo lvs
  LV          VG     Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  docker-pool docker twi-aot--- 39.96g             11.85  2.44
[ec2-user@]$ sudo vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  docker   1   1   0 wz--n- 100.00g 59.84g
```

When I upload new tasks, that partition increases and after some time docker says "I have no free space for you" and hangs

How can I clean up that partition? `docker ps -q|docker rmi` does not help

Comment: Hi, Why don't you stop your tasks with `aws ecs stop-task --task <UUID>` and try if the disk is released. I am pretty sure AWS would be using wrappers, so plain docker commands might be work (except for some)

Comment: no, disk is not released